# Oracle sql inline formula vs function performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

I am wondering if the use of inline computations have the same performance with  use of user defined function or the function creates more overhead?

I would prefer the second variant (with function) because of better readability.

**1st scenario** (inline computation)

```
select round(greatest(col1 - (col2/100)*col1,0),2) as res1, col1, col2 
from 
mytable
```

**2nd scenario**

**a. function:**

```
create or replace function calc(c1 number, c2 number) return number
begin 
   return round(greatest(col1 - (col2/100)*col1,0),2);
exception when others then 
   return 0;      
end;
```

**b. the query:**

```
select calc(col1,col2) as res1, col1, col2 
from 
mytable
```

Because in real life the source table could be quite large and there  is a significant number of more complicated computations - it would be good to know beforehand if converting the queries and making them more readable - would (or not) have a negative effect on overall execution speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an overhead to calling user-defined functions from SQL. Search for "context switching". This can be minimised using [`pragma udf`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/udf_pragma.htm) from 12c, or [`deterministic`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/function.htm#LNPLS01322) in earlier versions (or both).

For some detailed analysis of the options and their effect on performance, see:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

If you are likely to use your function in a `where` clause, you might also consider optimiser costing:

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=426

Comment: So I guess it is either or situation ... either readable or fast

Comment: Perhaps well placed comments in the code will help with readability.  But, this is correct, if you are going to churn a lot of data or your query is going to run many times, you have to be aware of context switching and it’s effects on performance.